# Webgazer used in eyetracking

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-video

I'm looking to hide the webgazer video feed using Javascript. The following code displays video feed and how to hide the video feed as my task is to give more space for displaying diagrams and text.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  webgazer.setRegression('ridge') /* currently must set regression and tracker */
    .setTracker('clmtrackr')
    .setGazeListener(gaze)
    .begin()
    .showPredictionPoints(true);

  var width = 320;
  var height = 240;
  var topDist = '100px';
  var leftDist = '400px';

  var setup = function() {
    var video = document.getElementById('webgazerVideoFeed');
    video.style.display = 'block';
    video.style.position = 'absolute';
    video.style.top = topDist;
    video.style.left = leftDist;
    video.width = width;
    video.height = height;
    video.style.margin = '0px';
    webgazer.params.imgWidth = width;
    webgazer.params.imgHeight = height;
    var overlay = document.createElement('canvas');
    overlay.id = 'overlay';
    overlay.style.position = 'absolute';
    overlay.width = width;
    overlay.height = height;
    overlay.style.top = topDist;
    overlay.style.left = leftDist;
    overlay.style.margin = '0px';
    document.body.appendChild(overlay);
    var cl = webgazer.getTracker().clm;

    function drawLoop() {
      requestAnimFrame(drawLoop);
      overlay.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
      if (cl.getCurrentPosition()) {
        cl.draw(overlay);
      }
    }
    drawLoop();
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first try a "hidden" Visibility through CSS Styles in the Video object's setup:

```
video.style.visibility = hidden;
```

Another option is to use Opacity to control transparency:

```
video.style.opacity = 0.0; //# range from min 0.0 (see-thru colors) up to 1.0 max (solid colors)
```

Finally you can try Z-Index for putting the Video object on a layer under everything:
(consider having a background fill via a screen-sized Div/Shape/Image, to hide the video behind it)

```
video.style.zIndex = -2; //# default layer level/index is 0
```